# How to unmask a editText intput type using a CheckBox

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I need to use a checkbox to add a show password feature in my android app. is there a particular way i could do this. I saw there is a method that can be used called SetTransformationMethod or something.

Can anyone help me with this please thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an EditText to enter password. And a CheckBox to show password or not.

When it checked, it show password. But when it not checked, it does show stars.

this code should work for you:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    password.setInputType(129);
                }
            }
        });
```

129 is the input type set when setting android:inputType="textPassword"

Hope this helps you.

Comment: yeah this works but then there is a bug i noticed. if you uncheck and check back the password becomes visible and invisble. and if you try unchecking and checking back again nothing happens

Comment: it was working fine with me. i have just given you piece of code to answer your question.rest of thing you have to manage your self. you can tell me where are you sticking.

Comment: yea yea i know what you mean. i said it unmasks the password and masks it back. but if i trying doing it for the second time it wouldnt unmask the password

Comment: so do you have a solution for it?